# Synthesizing error while designing 4-bit ALU in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

I'm trying to design a 4-bit ALU which does the following functions:

[image]

I've written the below Verilog code, and the simulation is working fine without any errors.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module alu_4_bit(
    
    input M,
    input S1,
    input S0,
    input C0,
    input [3:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    output reg [3:0] F,
    output reg Cout
    );

reg Cout_temp; // Internal Variable //

always @(*)

    begin 


                        case({M,S1,S0,C0})
                            
                            /* Logical Operations */
                            
                            4'b0000,4'b0001,4'b000x : assign F = A & B;
                            4'b0010,4'b0011,4'b001x : assign F = A | B;
                            4'b0100,4'b0101,4'b010x : assign F = A ^ B;
                            4'b0110,4'b0111,4'b011x : assign F = ~(A ^ B);
                            
                            /*Arithmetic Operations*/
                            
                            4'b1000 : assign {Cout,F} = {4'b000,A};
                            4'b1001 : assign {Cout,F} = A+1;
                            4'b1010 : assign {Cout,F} = A+B;
                            4'b1011 : assign {Cout,F} = A+B+1;
                            
            /* When there's negation of any one data entry, Cout also gets negated */
                            
                            4'b1101 : 
                            begin
                            assign {Cout_temp,F} = A+(~B)+1;
                            assign Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
                            end

                            
                            4'b1111 : 
                            begin
                            assign {Cout_temp,F} = (~A)+B+1;
                            assign Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
                            end
                            
                            
                            4'b1100 : 
                            begin
                            assign {Cout_temp,F} = A+(~B);
                            assign Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
                            end
                            
                            4'b1110 :
                            begin                           
                            assign {Cout_temp,F} = (~A)+B;
                            assign Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
                            end


                            default : assign {Cout,F} = 5'b00000;
                            
                        endcase 
                    
    end

endmodule
```

But, when I'm trying to synthesize the project and View the Technology/RTL Schematics, I'm encountering the following errors:

[image]

Can anyone point out where the mistake is and help me rectify it?

Comment: In the `always @(*)` block, you don't need the `assign` key word, the comb logic is implied.

Comment: Yes, this helped me in successfully generating the synthesis file.

Answer (score 1):

The error "unsupported procedural assignment for signal" means that your synthesis tool does not allow you to use the `assign` keyword inside the `always` block.  Assignments inside an `always` block are known as *procedural assignments*.  The `assign` keyword is typically used for *continuous assignments*, which are normally outside procedural blocks, such as `always` and `initial`.

The syntax in your code is supported by IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 10.6 *Procedural continuous assignments*.  However, it is not considered good coding style, and obviously all tools do not support it.

As suggested by the comment on your question, you should simply remove all the `assign` keywords in your code to avoid the errors.

After you fix those errors, there is another issue with your code: it will **infer unintended latches**.  You intend to infer purely combinational logic, but latches are sequential logic which retain state.

Your code retains state because it does not assign a value to `Cout` in all of the branches of the `case` statement, specifically those under the `/* Logical Operations */` comment.  Those branches only  make assignments to `F`.

One simple way to avoid the latches is to make an assignment to `Cout` just before the `case` statement:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module alu_4_bit (
    input M,
    input S1,
    input S0,
    input C0,
    input [3:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    output reg [3:0] F,
    output reg Cout
);

reg Cout_temp; // Internal Variable

always @(*) begin
    Cout = 0;
    case({M,S1,S0,C0})
        /* Logical Operations */

        4'b0000, 4'b0001, 4'b000x : F = A & B;
        4'b0010, 4'b0011, 4'b001x : F = A | B;
        4'b0100, 4'b0101, 4'b010x : F = A ^ B;
        4'b0110, 4'b0111, 4'b011x : F = ~(A ^ B);

        /*Arithmetic Operations*/

        4'b1000 : {Cout,F} = {4'b000,A};
        4'b1001 : {Cout,F} = A+1;
        4'b1010 : {Cout,F} = A+B;
        4'b1011 : {Cout,F} = A+B+1;

        /* When there's negation of any one data entry, Cout also gets negated */

        4'b1101 :
        begin
            {Cout_temp,F} = A+(~B)+1;
            Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
        end

        4'b1111 :
        begin
            {Cout_temp,F} = (~A)+B+1;
            Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
        end

        4'b1100 :
        begin
            {Cout_temp,F} = A+(~B);
            Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
        end

        4'b1110 :
        begin
            {Cout_temp,F} = (~A)+B;
            Cout = ~ Cout_temp;
        end

        default : {Cout,F} = 5'b00000;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```